# Converting current document's syntax highlighting based on it's extension in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, aiml

As AIML syntax isn't available for Sublime Text (which is normal because AIML is basically XML), is there a way to automatically convert all *.aiml* files opened by Sublime Text 3 to XML syntax highlighting (some sort of script to do this)? Whenever I have to reopen Sublime Text syntax highlighting restarts and I need to set highlighting from plain text to XML on every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `.aiml` file open in ST3, and the syntax highlighting set to XML:

- (Build 3118 onwards:) From the `Preferences` menu -> `Syntax Specific`:
- (Build 3114 and older:) From the `Preferences` menu -> `Settings - More` -> `Syntax Specific - User`

Paste in or type the following, so that the contents of the file look like:

```
{
    "extensions": ["aiml"]
}
```

And save it, and all `.aiml` files opened from now on should be highlighted as XML automatically.

Comment: @Nikola apologies, the JSON key should be `extensions` and not `file_extensions`. I have now updated my answer.

Comment: It works now, thanks!